# How to add AntPerformanceListener to Hudson job?

Tags: ant, build, hudson

I'm interested in being able to audit the time it takes for each ant task to run for jobs confirgured in Hudson v1.295. [This page](http://neopatel.blogspot.com/2009/09/timestamp-your-ant-build.html) shows how its possible via command line.

> ant -listener net.sf.antcontrib.perf.AntPerformanceListener deploy

I attempted to add this to a job by adding the following to Hudson job->configure->Invoke Ant and then adding the line at the top of Targets, but it did not work.

> -listener net.sf.antcontrib.perf.AntPerformanceListener

Would anyone know how to achieve this using Hudson?

Comment: What does "did not work" mean? Is there any error output? Please post more information, especially the output. Check one thing first: the `AntPerformanceListener` comes with ant-contrib, so you need to include that in your Ant's classpath (e.g. put the jar to $ANT_HOME/lib).